# Custom query method is returning an Object[] instead of a List of entities

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm calling a query method on an Entity and it returns `Object[]` instead of `List<EntityName>` I'm not sure why.

I have an Entity with default constructor, getters and setters. The getters are annotated with `@Column(name="field name")`.

Now I have and CRUD repository like this:

```java
@Transactional
public interface MyCrudRepo extends BaseCrudRepo <EntityClassName> {
  @Query("SELECT field1,field2,id FROM EntityClassName WHERE field1 = :param1 AND field2 = :param2")
      List<EntityClassName> queryMethod(
      @Param("param1") String param1,
      @Param("param2") String param2, Pageable page);
```

So I'm trying to get `List<EntityClassName>` when I call the method but it returns an `Object[]` I'm not sure what to do.

I also tried:

```java
@Query("SELECT ec FROM EntityClassName ec WHERE field1 = :param1 AND field2 = :param2")
```

But I get an query validation exception

when I invoke the `findAll()` method on the `MyCrudRepo` instance it returns a `List<EntityClassName>` like expected

Could it be because I have no constructor in the `EntityClassName` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your second query is «quite correct», but to access the fields of the instance, the instance name (`ec`) is missed. Thus, please consider using the following definition:

```java
public interface MyCrudRepo extends BaseCrudRepo<EntityClassName> {
    @Query(
        "SELECT ec FROM EntityClassName ec " +
        "WHERE ec.field1 = :param1 AND ec.field2 = :param2")
    List<EntityClassName> queryMethod(
        @Param("param1") String param1,
        @Param("param2") String param2,
        Pageable page
    ); 
}
```

## No-arg constructor of entity class

> Could it be because I have no constructor in the `EntityClassName` class?

There must be a no-arg constructor according to the JPA 2.1 specification ([JSR 338: Java™ Persistence 2.1, Final Release](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr338/index.html)), page 23:

> The entity class must have a no-arg constructor. The entity class may have other constructors as well. The no-arg constructor must be public or protected.